# Взять values с Object в Array TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, объекты

Пытаюсь спарсить с api запроса Array моделей, а приходит в ответ object
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

TypeScript пытаюсь из этого сделать Array[] вот таким способом :

```
this.projects = Object.values(this.projects);
```

в итоге выходит кривой Array :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как правильно оттуда вытянуть нужный мне Array с первого скрина?

вот http запрос :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ngOnit:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. Всё верно выходит потому что `Object.values()` возвращает значения ключей 2. Тайпскрипт тут не при чём

Comment: @EzioMercer уже понял, а каким способом можно вытянуть Array ?

Comment: Так `this.$values`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let temp = Object.values(this.projects);
this.projects = temp[1];
```

Кривой костыль который работает ;)

Answer (score 0):

в `ngOnInit`

```
this.projects.$values
```

---

`this.projects` - это объект. А к полям объекта стоит обращаться через точку

---

`Object.values` же возвращает массив значений объекта.

Вы можете написать `Object.values(this.projects)[1]`, но так делать не стоит

Comment: в первом случае с this.projects.$values пробую вот так : 
this.projects = this.projects.values; пишет ошибку IterableIterator is not assignable...
так же если : this.projects.$values то пишет - property $values does not exist on Type ProjectModel[]
во втором случае : this.projects = Object.values(this.projects)[1]; ошибка - 
Type ProjectModel is missing following properties...

Comment: как я читал через this.projects.values работало в старых версиях, сейчас же в новой версии не пашет и многие советовали откатить typescript до es2015 , но пробовал в tsconfig менять target : "es2015" , не помогло(